# Переклад словосполучення "horizontally gifted"

Tags: переклад, from-english, відповідник

Cловосполучення "horizontally gifted" вживається, щоб описати повну людину, не образивши її. Жодний із відомих мені онлайн словників ([Гугл](https://translate.google.com/?hl=uk#en/uk/horizontally%20gifted), [Глосб](https://uk.glosbe.com/en/uk/horizontally%20gifted), [Мета](http://translate.meta.ua/ua/)) не зміг коректно перекласти це словосполучення.

То чи є в українській мові якийсь відповідник? Бо наскільки я знаю навіть якщо назвати людину "гладкою", то її це може образити. Що вже говорити про такі прикметники як "товстий", "відгодований", "жирний".

Comment: Можливо: людина не в формі

Comment: Horizontally challenged = «Людина з обмеженою горизонтальною мобільністю». Horizontally gifted це досить образливо навіть англійською, бо виглядає пародіюванням словосполучень для інвалідності.

Comment: @EugeneUvin відповідь скореговано. Сподіваюся, що тепер думка виражена більш зрозуміло.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Це правда, що horizontally gifted може звучати коректно у порівнянні з fat. Проте це не означає, що людина, яку описують за допомогою цього словосполучення, не може образитись. Може він або вона намагається схуднути і не хоче таких слів, навіть коректних, по відношенню до себе взагалі. Так і з українськими відповідниками. Можна сказати "не в найкращій фізичній формі" або "пухкий", що, здається, звучить менш образливо, ніж "товстий" або "гладкий", але почуття тієї людини можна зачепити все одно. Тому будьте обережні.

Доречі, ось [тут](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/474163/the-use-of-horizontally-gifted/474167#474167) було поставлене питання про вживання `horizontally gifted`. Люди одностайні у тому, що не варто вживати цей вираз, бо він більш саркастичний, ніж коректний.